# get same result from c# linq as SQL statement

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am trying to figure out how to get all the notifications from relations that get multiple notifications, because i want to combine these notifications to 1 notification so the relation wil only get 1 e-mail instead of multiple.

I created the following SQL statement, which for as far as i can tell does what i want:

```
select distinct r.Notificatie
       , r.RelatieNr
  FROM [configuratie].[dbo].[NotificatieRecID] r
  join [configuratie].[dbo].[Notificatie] n on r.Notificatie = n.ID
  where n.Verzonden = 0
  and r.RelatieNr in(select RelatieNr from [configuratie].[dbo].[NotificatieRecID]
                       group by RelatieNr having count(*) > 1)
                       order by r.RelatieNr
```

It returns the following

```
Notification                            Relation
3A2A53B9-D92A-4504-874D-5A901AD01041    114147
4C499F6C-53C8-49E0-B529-8B045819BE10    114147
AF4ED8CB-D033-47A4-96AE-F379BB484532    114147
977885C5-4C12-431B-AB72-59383B1824C6    303327
3A2A53B9-D92A-4504-874D-5A901AD01041    303327
4C499F6C-53C8-49E0-B529-8B045819BE10    303327
AF4ED8CB-D033-47A4-96AE-F379BB484532    303327
```

Later in my c# code i will get all the values from the different notifications and simply combine them but first i need to write this SQL statement in a way i can use it with linq in c#.
I have no idea how to do `SELECT DISTINCT`, `and r.RelatieNr in` and `group by RelatieNr having count(*) > 1`

Could someone provide me with an example? (it does not have to be 1 linq statement, i've kind of figured that's impossible, though i would like as little temporary Lists/Iqueriables since the tables are huge)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following

```
 var details= (from r in NotificatieRecID
              join n in Notificatie on r.Notificatie=n.ID
              where n.Verzonden=0 &&
              (from t in NotificatieRecID
               group t by t.RelatieNr into grp
               where grp.Count()>1
               select grp.Key).Contains(r.relatieNr)
              select new {
                 Notificate=r.Notificatie,
                 RelatieNr=r.RelatieNr
  }).Distinct();
```